# Why do I get a "Class 'Yii' not found" error?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii

With YII, I'm trying to make a query from a page called from ajax

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Test request',          
    array('ajax/z1_gerar_excel.php',
            'type'=>'POST',
            'data' => array('sql' => $sql)
        ),
    array('update'=>'#req_res'
    )
);
?>

<div id="req_res">...</div>
```

and here is the AJAX page:

```
$sql = $_REQUEST['data']['sql'];
//echo $sql;
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$dataReader = $command->query();
$cont_l = 1;
while(($row = $dataReader->read()) !== false) 
{
echo "<br>Linha $cont_l: ";
print_r($row);
$cont_l++;
}// WHILE EOF

$connection->active = false;
```

and I have the following problem, the YII class is not initialized in the page called from ajax, so I get the following result:

> Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found in D:\Programas\Xampp\Instalado2\htdocs\atayo-teste\ajax\z1_gerar_excel.php on line 4

I've only been using YII for one week. How can I resolve this error?

UPDATE:

So i tried change it to a more YII way, i followed the example from http://lostmahbles.com/simple-yii-ajaxlink/ and add this to my view(z1_sql.php):

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
  "Link Text",
  Yii::app()->createUrl( 'application/controllers/RelatorioController/ajaxRequest' ),
  array( // ajaxOptions
    'type' => 'POST',
    'beforeSend' => "function( request )
                     {
                       // Set up any pre-sending stuff like initializing progress indicators
                     }",
    'success' => "function( data )
                  {
                    // handle return data
                    alert( data );
                  }",
    'data' => array( 'val1' => '1', 'val2' => '2' )
  ),
  array( //htmlOptions
    'href' => Yii::app()->createUrl( 'application/controllers/RelatorioController/ajaxRequest' ),
    'class' => 'actionAjaxRequest'
  )
);
```

and this to my controller(RelatorioController.php):

```
public function accessRules()
{
  return array(
    array('allow',
          'actions'=>array('ajaxrequest'),
          'users'=>array('@'),
    ),
    array('deny',  // deny all users
          'users'=>array('*'),
    ),
  );
}

   public function actionAjaxRequest()
{
  $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
  $val2 = $_POST['val2'];

  echo "some sort of response";

  Yii::app()->end();
}
```

but i`m getting a 404 ERROR. And again, really noobie into YII, so anything at all helps...

Comment: Did you check line 4? This `$connection=Yii::app()->db;`

Comment: You're missing this: `require_once('path/to/yii/framework/yii.php');` maybe?

Comment: You better have a **really good reason** for executing running arbitrary user queries. This is extremely dangerous to do on a public site of any sort.

Comment: It looks like you are requesting a normal php file in that ajax link 'z1_gerar_excel.php' and that is most likely out of the scope of the framework. Use a Yii action for that and then the Yii class would be available.
And like tadman said, don't execute anything user entered without validation/sanitation in your db.

Comment: When asking a question, don't dump tags in the title. Try to put an actual sentence (preferably a question) in there.

Comment: `POST ajax/z1_gerar_excel.php?data[sql]=DROP TABLE user, group, log, documents, backup;` Goodbye, database. Why would you **ever** allow users to run custom queries against your database?

Answer (score 0):

You're not requesting a Yii php function/page.
Change your code to something like this: (not tested)

```
<?php
echo ajaxLink('text', array('ajax/z1_gerar_excel'), array(
    'type' =>'POST',
    'data' => array('sql' => $sql),
), array(
    'update'=>'#req_res' // this array is for htmlOptions, so I think you want this parameter in the array with the ajax options
));
?>
```

Make sure you have an ajax controller with a function `z1_gerar_excel`.

For more information about the parameters of `ajaxLink` take a look at:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail